# Can we play 360 video using GvrView of google VR android sdk?

Tags: android, google-cardboard, google-vr, virtual-reality, 360-virtual-reality

By using `VrVideoView` we can play 360 video but my issue is that, we cannot put video controller such as (Previous,Next,Play,Pause) in Bi-rectangular View. So how we can add this controller in `VrVideoView` (If we can). And I found that we cannot play 360 video using `GvrView`. So i just want to add video controller in 360 video in Bi-rectangular view.